# Laravel: Call git pull in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, git, deployment

If I push my local repository to Bitbucket then a webhook posts a request to my production server.

In my Laravel app, I have created a route for that webhook, which is excluded by CSRF. I want that my production server automatically makes a pull request. Here is my current code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class DeployController extends Controller
{
    public function start(Request $request, $token)
    {
      Log::info('Got Webhook request! Nice: '. $request);

      if($token != '123124123'){
        Log::error('Token of request not matching: ' . $request);
        dd('Try another day.');
      }

      $data   = [];
      $data[] = shell_exec('whoami');
      $data[] = shell_exec('cd ~/www/memberportal || exit');
      $data[] = shell_exec('git pull origin master');

      dd($data);
    }
}
```

The code is executed when I do a `git push origin master` command, but this is what it returs:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "wp9*********\n"
  1 => null
  2 => null
]
```

Why is `git pull origin master` returning null? And how do I pass my Bitbucket passwort that is usually requested when I pull from terminal:

[image]